# Error 404 in update commands

Tags: 13.04

I am a new ubuntu user.
when I run `sudo apt-get update` this error message appears:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
```

What to do now ?

Comment: What command did you used to update? Please, past the *full* output. Have you checked the internet connection?

Comment: Raring has reached End-Of-Life, and its packages aren't (or shouldn't be) available in the regular repos. You will need to upgrade to Saucy (13.10) or Trusty (14.04) for updates and support.

Answer (score 0):

If the 404 error was due to an additional repository that has been added to `/etc/apt/sources.list` then its easier to add # character to the start of the line to comment out the offending repository i.e.

1. Install gksu first

   `sudo apt-get install gksu`
2. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` as Root

   `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
3. Go to line 52-53, add # character to the start line 52-53 like mine [image: source list]
4. Save it, done !

Answer (score 0):

I think the repository "extra" not longer supported for version 13.04. I solve the problem commenting the line. Using a VM with version 14.04 Extra repository works.

```
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
#deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
#deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
```